# Merging two dataframes based on condition in a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two dataframes (`df1` & `df2`) based on the column `PERMNO` resp. `LPERMNO`:
`df1.merge(df2, left_on='PERMNO', right_on='LPERMNO')`

However, when merging I also need to consider that the column `date` of `df1` lies in between the range of the two columns `LINKDT` & `LINKENDDT` of `df2`, since `df2` holds different information for each row (see column `PRC` of `df2`).

For example, index `[0,1]` of `df1` should merge with index `0` of `df2` 
and index `[2,3]` of `df1` should merge with index `2` of `df2`, since the value of `date` is within the two columns `LINKDT` & `LINKENDDT`.

Unfortunately, I am bit lost here, so any help is appreciated!

***df1***

```
    PERMNO  date
0   66325   2006-03-30
1   66325   2006-06-30
2   66325   2015-09-30
3   66325   2015-12-30
```

***df2:***

```
    LPERMNO LINKDT      LINKENDDT   PRC
0   66325   1992-07-01  2014-04-30  10
1   66325   1983-09-23  1992-06-30  12
2   66325   2014-05-01  2019-12-31  8.5
```

---

***UPDATE***:
***expected output***

Output dataframe has shape 2'000'000x180.

```
    PERMNO  date        LPERMNO   LINKDT      LINKENDDT    PRC   
0   66325   2006-03-30  66325     1992-07-01  2014-04-30   10
1   66325   2006-06-30  66325     1992-07-01  2014-04-30   10
2   66325   2015-09-30  66325     2014-05-01  2019-12-31   8.5
3   66325   2015-12-30  66325     2014-05-01  2019-12-31   8.5
```

Comment: can you write the expected output?

Comment: I've updated the the question. @gonzalorivera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['PERMNO'], right_on=['LPERMNO'])

# if ['date', 'LINKDT', 'LINKENDDT'] already are in datetime format, ignore this three lines
df_merged['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged['date'])
df_merged['LINKDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged['LINKDT'])
df_merged['LINKENDDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged['LINKENDDT'])

# Assuming LINKDT < LINKENDDT
df_merged = df_merged[(df_merged['date'] >= df_merged['LINKDT']) & (df_merged['date'] <= df_merged['LINKENDDT'])]
```

Output:

```
    PERMNO       date  LPERMNO     LINKDT  LINKENDDT   PRC
0    66325 2006-03-30    66325 1992-07-01 2014-04-30  10.0
3    66325 2006-06-30    66325 1992-07-01 2014-04-30  10.0
8    66325 2015-09-30    66325 2014-05-01 2019-12-31   8.5
11   66325 2015-12-30    66325 2014-05-01 2019-12-31   8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any simpler/faster/better way to do it, but this is what I'm suggesting you. The merging you are trying to get seems a little too complicated for .merge(), tried using conditions on columns instead.

```
permno = []
date = []
linkdt = []
linkenddt = []
prc = []
for i in range(0, df1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, df2.shape[0]):
        if (df1['PERMNO'][i]==df2['LPERMNO'][j]) & (df1['date'][i] > df2['LINKDT'][j]) & (df1['date'][i] < df2['LINKENDDT'][j]):
            permno.append(df1['PERMNO'][i])
            date.append(df1['date'][i])
            linkdt.append(df2['LINKDT'][j])
            linkenddt.append(df2['LINKENDDT'][j])
            prc.append(df2['PRC'][j])

merged = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(permno, linkdt, date, linkenddt, prc)), 
                       columns = ['PERMNO', 'LINKDT', 'LINKENDDT', 'PRC'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my dataframe has shape 2'000'000x180, so your solution would be very work as well as computationally intensive  Thank you anyway though. @Kiwi

Comment: You're right, with such data it would be a never ending loop. I'm sorry I couldn't be of help.